# Use the same function on multiple gridviews/tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have 6 asp gridviews that need the same calculations done on each of them. I could hard code the function 6 times over but looking for a more efficient way of doing it.

What I'm doing: There are 3 input boxes on each row, of each gv and I need to calculate the average and send it to a lbl in the last column.

Here is what I've done for the first gv:

```
function calculate() {
    //********************
    //Development Grid
    //********************
    //Find the number of rows in the grid
    var rowCount = $('#devGV tr').length;
    //Iterate through each row looking for the input boxes
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        //convert the total variable to an int
        var total = 0;
        parseInt(total);
        //This variable is for tracking the number of actual fields that are populated.
        //Not all the text fields will always be needed, so the average will not always be calculated by dividing by 3
        var averNum = 0;
        //Iterate through each text box
        $("#devGV tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(":input[type=text]").each(function () {
            //Convert the value to an int
            var thisValue = parseInt($(this).val());
            //In the value is blank, change it to 0 for calculation purposes
            if (isNaN(thisValue) || thisValue == 0) {
                thisValue = 0;
            }
            else {
                averNum += 1;
            }
            total = (total + thisValue);
        });
        //Populate the totals label for each row
        total = total / averNum;
        total = total.toFixed(2);
        //In the value is blank, change it to 0 for calculation purposes
        if (isNaN(total)) {
            total = 0;
        }
        $("#devGV tr:eq(" + i + ")").find("[class$='RowTotals']").text(total);
    }
}
```

The above function is being trigger by 'onBlur' on each of the text fields. Is there a way I can make this block work for all the gridviews? I'm sure its just a matter of updating the selectors but I'm at a loss on how to do that.

Comment: You have hardcoded gridview id in your function (#devGV). Perhaps try to pass the gridview as an argument of the calculate function?

Comment: yeah thats what I'm thinking, but I cant figure out how to get the gridview id of the textbox that was altered, and then how to subsitude that for the places in the code that has #devGV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest is probably to pass a jquery object to calculate function:

```
function calculate(gv) {
```

Then use `.find()` in place of where you have the ID, for instance like this for the "find the number of rows in the grid":

```
var rowCount = gv.find('tr').length;
```

The reason I say it's easier to pass a jQuery object into the function (rather than the string ID of it, say) is that it lets you do something like this:

```
$('.some-gridview-css-class').each(function() {
    calculate($(this));
});
```

Obviously replace that selector with whatever selector will identify your 6 gridviews for you.

EDIT: Oh I didn't read carefully enough. You want to do it onblur of a textbox. That means you want something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(body).on('blur', 'input-fields-selector', function() {
        calculate($(this).closest('gridview-selector'));
    });
});
```

You have to replace input-fields-selector and gridview-selector with selectors to find the appropriate fields (which will depend on your HTML).

Comment: How could I call the calculate(gv) function from the onBlur event of the text field? Not sure how to pass the gridview object to the function

Comment: Tried the revision, i can get the function to fire when focus is taken from the text fields, and I can count the number of rows in the gv so it's picking up the gridview...ty. The only issue I have now is the `$("#devGV tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(":input[type=text]").each(function () {`. How do I use the gv object instead of the hard coded `#devGV`?

Comment: Same substitution as the other line, instead of `$("#devGV tr:eq(" + i + ")")` just `gv.find("tr:eq(" + i + ")")`

Comment: Ok so its working, but only on the first gridview. When I input numbers in the other gv's, the event triggers, but it isnt pickin up the gridview object. For the selector in the activation I used `calculate($(this).closest('.gridViewClass'));` and added that class to each of the gv's

Comment: When you say "isn't picking up the gridview object", what exactly is happening?

Comment: When I do a `var rowCount = gv.find('tr').length;` `alert(rowCount);` it returns 0 when I change the text fields on any gridview other than the first one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70707/discussion-between-kieran-quinn-and-chrisv).